# Can I use placement new with class array?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast, placement-new

Consider this code:

```cpp
struct Block {
    alignas(int) unsigned char data[sizeof(int)];
};

int main() {
    Block buff[sizeof(double) / sizeof(int)];
    ::new(&buff) double();
    double d = *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<double*>(&buff));

    return 0;
}
```

Is this usage correct? Does the `reinterpret_cast` lead to undefined behavior?

Comment: *Why* do you need to do anything like this?

Comment: looks legal.  could have unaligned access which will break some CPUs.  I would try to find a better way.  What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I've seen similar usage in the llvm's code, so I'm wondering if this usage is well-defined. See [this](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/__memory/shared_ptr.h#L942)

Comment: @NathanOliver See [this](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/__memory/shared_ptr.h#L942), I'm trying to write some similar code, but I don't know if this is the correct usage, because the standard library sometimes uses some magic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has defined behavior, assuming `double` doesn't have stronger alignment requirement than `int` and `sizeof(double)` is an integer multiple of `sizeof(int)`.

However, still, if `sizeof(double) > sizeof(int)`, then there is no `unsigned char` array which could provide storage for the `double` object and so `::new(&buff) double()` will end the lifetime of the `buff` object (and all of its subobjects). The `double` object is then not nested within `buff`, but instead reuses its storage.

In that case it wouldn't matter whether you use your `Block` type or any other type of suitable alignment and size, as long as the destructor is trivial. If the destructor is non-trivial, then the implicit destructor call at the end of the scope would cause undefined behavior if at that point no `Block` objects transparently replacing the original ones were alive in `buff`'s storage.

Also, there is no guarantee by the standard that there won't be padding after `data`, so that the calculations might not behave in the way you expect, although it can't affect what I wrote above. There is also only a guarantee that the offset of the `data` member in the class is zero because the class is standard-layout.

Comment: So dereference the pointer returned by `std::launder` is safe? If the destructor is non-trivial, I should call destructor explicitly?

Comment: @ValueError Yes it is safe, under the assumptions I stated. But that's not really interesting. You are always allowed to reuse storage of any object in this way. No, calling the destructor explicitly would be worse. The point is that at the end of the scope there is an implicit call to the destructor of each of `buff`'s `Block` elements. If the lifetime of these objects has already ended, because you reused their storage, then that call would have UB. Generally calling member functions out-of-lifetime is UB. There is an exception for the implicit destructor call if the destructor is trivial.

Comment: @ValueError So what you would need to do with a non-trivial destructor, and assuming that the sizes happen to be so that the first `data` array can't fully provide storage to the `double` object, is that you would need to placement-`new` `Block` elements again into the array before the end of `buff`'s scope is reached. The implicit destructor calls will then act on these new `Block` objects.

Comment: In other words, I can also allocate memory on the heap and then deallocate it without calling the `Block`'s destructor?

Comment: @ValueError Yes, using dynamic storage wouldn't cause that potentially issue with a non-trivial destructor, because then there is no implicit destructor call at all. In that case it is up to you anyway to decide whether and when the destructor is called. (Still, calling a destructor on an object out-of-lifetime explicitly will cause undefined behavior.)